How to draw a map and add click event on each region?
I've been working on building an app using React Native.
What I want to do is draw a map(it can be just an image) and add click event on each region.
For example, just like the image below, I want to draw a map and make the each colored region to be clickable(need to be navigated to another screen).
Is it possible to map the click event depends on the region sections in the image?


For such case you need to use SVG map and react-native-svg
Just add onPress event on every region.
